# Get drawable for different screen density at runtime

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources, android-resolution

I want to print sizes of all drawables at run-time. So if I am on `hdpi` device then I can print the size of `hdpi` drawables but how to get access to, lets say `mdpi` and `xhdpi` as well? I can get access to all drawables resource ids with following code:

```
final Class<R.drawable> c = R.drawable.class;
final Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();

for (int i = 0, max = fields.length; i < max; i++) {
    final int resourceId;
    try {
        resourceId = fields[i].getInt(drawableResources);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        continue;
    }
    /* make use of resourceId for accessing Drawables here */
}
```

Comment: You can **calculate** them.

Comment: Ok consider a scenario where I have a huge app and I realized that developers messed up by placing wrong sizes in different folders. So now I want to print actual sizes for drawables embed in my app for different screen sizes. Anyway I just found that I can do `context.getResources().getDrawableForDensity(resourceId, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM)` or invoke same with `DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH` etc

Comment: Gonna post it as answer after testing it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I found it, Basically you explicitly ask for a particular density drawable like this:

```
Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawableForDensity(id, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH);
```

or preferably this version

```
Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawableForDensity(id, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH, theme);
```