# Can I access an icon (programmatically) from a folder dedicated for another screen resolution?

Tags: android, icons

If I am using an Android device which prefers drawables from, say drawable-hdpi, can I still use a drawable from, for example the drawable-xxhdpi folder in my program? (Note: I have complete sets of icons for all resolutions).

(I would like to use extra high-res icons for some parts of my app)...

Comment: For best practice you need to put the different `density bitmap/image` to there specified  folder instead of getting it from different drawable folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a different drawable of another density using this method:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawableForDensity(id, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH, theme);
```

You can check the answer in the next post: [Get drawable for different screen density at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30254147/get-drawable-for-different-screen-density-at-runtime) and in the [Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html)